# Verify that a grammar is LL(1)

Tags: antlr4, ll-grammar

I want to verify that my ANTLR 4 grammar is LL(1). [There is an option to do just that in older versions of ANTLR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16745334/41071). Is there something similar in ANTLR 4?

I looked through through [the documentation](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/ANTLR+4+Documentation), but didn't find anything. Though especially [the page on options](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Options) seems to be lacking, I didn't even find a list of all possible options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the design goals of ANTLR 4 is allowing language designers to focus on writing accurate grammars rather than worrying about characteristics like "LL(1)" which have little to no impact on users of the language.

However, it is likely that you can identify an LL(1) grammar by examining the generated parser. If there are no calls to `adaptivePredict` in the generated code, then the grammar is LL(1). The *intent* is for the inverse to also be true, but considering a call to `adaptivePredict` produces the same result as the inline version of an LL(1) decision, we have not rigorously evaluated this.